# Last Header cell not copied by using ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I use below code to copy data from closed workbook ("Sheet1") using ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks .

the data copied successfully as my specified requirements **except** `Last Header cell`.

I tried to change `HDR=NO to HDR=Yes` in ADO connection , But the same problem.

As always: great thanks for your help.

[image]
[image]

```
Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)

    Dim rsCon As Object, rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String, szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO"";"

    If SourceSheet = "" Then   'Workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    If Not rsData.EOF Then   ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data

        If Header = False Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
          Else
        End If
      Else: MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If
    
    rsData.Close  ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub GetData_Example4()    'Select one file with GetOpenFilenamewhere
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String, MyPath As String
    Dim FName As Variant

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    ChDrive MyPath
    ChDir MyPath
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*")

    If FName = False Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        GetData FName, "Sheet1", "A1:D5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), False, False
    End If

    ChDrive SaveDriveDir
    ChDir SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean, you don't get the headers at all or just last one?  You need to loop rsData.fields names and poulate them.

Comment: @ Nathan_Sav only the last one not copied

Comment: Where is your code that populates the headers?

Comment: I already set Header to False by assigning HDR=NO  @ Nathan_Sav

Comment: Look round about the centre of this page    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/transfer-excel-data-from-ado-recordset  the header setting, sets that row 1 contains field names

Comment: Would help to show a screenshot of your sample data, and one of the results you get.

Comment: @Tim Williams :Added screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header is likely missing because ADO has decided that column is numeric and so the header gets auto-converted to `null` because it's not numeric. You're telling ADO that row1 is part of the data when you use HDR=No.

You can try moving it's position in the source data and it should still show that behavior.

You really *don't* want ADO to treat your headers like they're part of your dataset, so you need to either skip them in your SQL (by excluding the header row from the range you supply) or use HDR=Yes in the connection.

If using HDR=Yes then you'll need to add some code to your sub to read each field name in the recordset and populate a header row on the results sheet before using `CopyFromRecordSet`.

Comment: you are right about **ADO has decided that column is numeric** I changed it to text then it worked without problem. the issue now if Header contains merged cells , the result is blank row ,therefor  I preferred to set HDR=NO. Do you advice to accept your answer and create a new question or you can you edit your answer ?

Comment: If you don't want to query the header then leave your HDR=No and query instead from the second row on (that's what I meant by "skip them in your SQL" - edited above to make that clearer).   Ranges with merged cells are not good candidates for querying data using SQL.